# DataFrame in CSV

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm trying to make 2 files in Python. One named "1.csv" with number 1 and one named "2.csv" with number 2, but I have some problems. Any help?

```
import pandas as pd

HM = ['1', '2']
for h in HM:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'number':h})
    df.to_csv(h + '.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: What is your problem? Which error is thrown? What is the expected behaviour? What is the actual behaviour? Please refer to [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not pass scalar values for the columns.
You can either use a list:

```
import pandas as pd

HM = ['1', '2']
for h in HM:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'number':[h]})
    df.to_csv(h + '.csv', index=False)
```

or use scalar values and pass an index:

```
import pandas as pd

HM = ['1', '2']
for h in HM:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'number':h},index=[0])
    df.to_csv(h + '.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

To create a dataframe, you can use the sample code below to fit your own needs.

```py
#Import pandaa 
import pandas as pd 
  
# Create a list
data = [['Basketball', 'Monday'], ['Baseball', 'Saturday'], ['Football', 'Sunday']] 
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Sport', 'Day']) 
  
# print dataframe. 
df 

#Write the dataframe to a csv
df.to_csv('path/for/output.csv', sep='\t')
```

**EDIT**

For your specific problem, you can do the following to create two separate csv files.

```
import pandas as pd

HM = ['1', '2']
for h in HM:
    df = pd.DataFrame({'number':[h]})
    df.to_csv(h + '.csv', index=False)
```